# Can I use Bluehost as a host for a .fr domain, Gandi.net being my registrar?

Tags: dns, bluehost

**I have a .fr domain registered at Gandi.net.
Yesterday I subscribed to Bluehost for the hosting** (being a beginner, it is easier to install Wordpress through Bluehost).

I had to change the DNS on Gandi. I did that and also created a DNS zone on Gandi (not sure if I should have done both). It worked and I started creating my website today.

All of a sudden, the website just switched back to Gandi as a host (since the default Gandi page is showing instead of my Wordpress page).

**Now I just read this page:**
https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/536

**Does this mean that I will not be able at all to host a .fr domain through Bluehost?** 
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the article says, get the A record for your server from Bluehost (just ask them for it) and go to Gandi's control panel and set the A record to that IP.

If you also use email on that domain, set the MX record in the same way (ask Bluehost for it and change it in Gandi's control panel).